# Skip line in text file which starts with '#' via KornShell (ksh)

Tags: shell, unix, scripting, ksh

I am trying to write a script which reads a text file and saves each line to a string. I would also like the script to skip any lines which start with a hash symbol. Any suggestions?

Comment: what if there is million lines..will u stroe in million strings?

Comment: no I won't stroe them because there won't be a million lines. I also said, A string, as in ONE string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not leave skipping lines to `ksh`. E.g. do this:

```
grep -v '^#' INPUTFILE | while IFS="" read line ; do echo $line ; done
```

And instead of the `echo` part do whatever you want.

Or if `ksh` does not support this syntax:

```
grep -v '^#' INPUTFILE > tmpfile
while IFS="" read line ; do echo $line ; done < tmpfile
rm tmpfile
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I am getting, 'write error on standard output the pipe is being closed' any ideas??

Answer (score 2):

```
while read -r line; do
    [[ "$line" = *( )#* ]] && continue
    # do something with "$line"
done < filename
```

look for "File Name Patterns" or "File Name Generation" in the ksh man page.